# Tailwindcss 3 with Angular 13 - new styles don't show after ctrl+s livereaload

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, livereload

I am using Tailwindcss 3 with Angular 13.
When I apply new class (for example bg-cyan-500) the style is not added into final .css file and the change is not visible.
I have to kill the "ng serve" command and re-run it. After I re-run "ng serve" command everything works fine.
But it impossible to rerun "ng serve" with every css change I made.

Comment: where do you add your CSS class? and you add this CSS file to angular.json in styles[] section and try it?

Comment: I add the class to div: <div class="bg-cyan-500">hello</div>. 
I also added 
import "tailwindcss/base";
import "tailwindcss/components";
import "tailwindcss/utilities";
into styles.css

In Tailwind version 2 it was working perfectly.

Comment: this link is useful for your problem https://trungk18.com/experience/configure-tailwind-css-with-angular/

Answer (score 0):

updating angular version via CLI [source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/22447#issuecomment-1027845745)

```
ng update
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {    
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}"],    
}
```

Also create a postcss.config.js in the root of your project and paste this

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    }
}
```

This is for Angular 13 and Tailwind 3

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.9" in your `package.json` file. After that you have to run this command `npm install` .
re-run your project now. It works for me.